# Sort data based on conditions

Tags: r, sorting

I have a (x) data frame in R with 5 numeric columns and apart from this one information is sorting order to be followed in form of a vector i.e.

```
1, 0, 2, 4, 3
```

dataset

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1  2  3  4  5
3  13 12 1  4
6  4  6  5  3
```

Expected result

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
3  13 12 1  4
1  2  2  4  5
6  4  6  5  3
```

this vector define the sorting order that first column needs to be sorted first then 3rd column then 5th column and then 4th column. manually it can be done as

```
x = x[order(x[1],)]
x = x[order(x[3],)]
x = x[order(x[5],)]
x = x[order(x[4],)]
rownames(x) = NULL
```

Problem is for 5 columns, it is easy but it is complicated for 100s of columns.
 any lead to this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Add a reproducible example with the expected output.

Comment: added a simple example for your reference sir

Comment: I am confused. What is the vector `1, 0, 2, 4, 3`. What is `1 3 5 4` ? Also the dataset and the expected output isn't clear to me.

Comment: vector says sort the first column first then 3rd column then 5th column and then 4th column

Comment: 1,0,2,4,3 defines which column is to be sorted first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a `match` on the original vector and then use a `for` loop to get the output

```
i1 <-  match(seq_along(x), vec, nomatch = 0)
i1 <- i1[i1!=0]
for(i in i1){
 x <- x[order(x[i]),]
}

x
#   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
# 2  3 13 12  1  4
# 1  1  2  3  4  5
# 3  6  4  6  5  3
```

#### data

```
x <- structure(list(v1 = c(1L, 3L, 6L), v2 = c(2L, 13L, 4L), v3 = c(3L, 
12L, 6L), v4 = c(4L, 1L, 5L), v5 = c(5L, 4L, 3L)), .Names = c("v1", 
"v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

vec <- c(1, 0, 2, 4, 3)
```